# HTML5 Background Video not playing in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I've set up a full width / height video background using Video JS [http://videojs.com/] which behaves correctly in Safari, Chrome and Firefox but only works intermittently in IE9. The site can be seen here: http://www.snclbrand.com/

Having spent much time digging through Google, and Stack Overflow, I've added extra code to the .htaccess file so it looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


AddType audio/mpeg mp3
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
AddType audio/ogg ogg
AddType audio/ogg oga
AddType audio/webm webma
AddType audio/wav wav

AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/mp4 m4v
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/webm webmv
```

Sadly, this hasn't helped and in IE's developer tools this error shows up in the console when the video won't play: **Video Error[object Object]**

I'm not experienced enough with jQuery / HTML5 video to diagnose what's going on, any pointers or help is gratefully received.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: did you embed different video codecs? IE9 only plays H.264 native, not ogg and WebM. if you did so, try to play the video via drag'n' drop in IE9 to check if the problem occurs in the video file itself (working on mac, so no possibility to check direct at your page..)

Comment: It's a mystery why some (and very few) work in IE and Microsoft is no help whatsoever. As always, modern code works in any other browser but not in IE and evidence of these video issues are rampant on SO and around the internet. I believe it has to do with knowing the secret encoding sauce to make this work.